# Loop through each TR and add Attribute to TD with Array Data from TH

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I've filled an array with the TH values and would like to add an attribute to each TD in each TR. I have setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buildakicker/1g33sp22/3/) to get this all working.

Basically, I am doing the following:

```
//Fill ths array with header text
$(".table th").each(function () {
    var thdatatrimmed = trimIt($(this).html());
    ths.push(thdatatrimmed);
});
```

and then get the tds and add the attributes:

```
   //total trs
var trlen = $(".table tr").length;
console.log(trlen);
//add header to data-title attribute to each TD
for (var j = 0; j < trlen; j++) {
    //console.log(ths.length);
    for (var i = 0, len = ths.length; i < len; i++) {
        //console.log(ths[i]);
        $('td:eq('+i+')').attr("data-title", ths[i]);
    }
}
```

Where I am stumbling is how to apply the 11 THs to each row of TDs and then reset it for the next row. The above will do it to the first tr>td row, but not the next ones. What am I missing?

Comment: So you're trying to assign the `data-title` attribute of the `td`s in each column to the `th` of that column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/1g33sp22/4/

```js
//array to fill with ths
var ths = new Array();

//Clean the text
function trimIt(x) {
    return x.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
}
//Fill ths array with header text
$(".table th").each(function () {
    var thdatatrimmed = trimIt($(this).html());
    console.log(thdatatrimmed);
    ths.push(thdatatrimmed);
});

//total trs
var trlen = $(".table tr").length;
console.log(trlen);
//add header to data-title attribute to each TD
for (var j = 0; j < trlen; j++) {
    //console.log(ths.length);
    for (var i = 0, len = ths.length; i < len; i++) {
        //console.log(ths[i]);
        $('table tr').eq(j).find('td').eq(i).attr('data-title', ths[i]);
        //$('td:eq('+i+')').attr("data-title", ths[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this solution :

```
for (var j = 0; j < trlen; j++) {

  $('.table tr:nth-child('+ (2+j) +')').find('td').each(function(i,v){
     $(this).attr("data-title", ths[i]);
  });    
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/3rn0eydh/)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is the simplest, selecting every `td` element in each column at once, instead of selecting every single one separately, like the rest are doing. It will also be faster, as running the jQuery function on each element is costly.

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqh2myhk/)**

```
//Fill ths array with header text
$(".table th").each(function () {
    var thdatatrimmed = trimIt($(this).html());
    ths.push(thdatatrimmed);
});

// loop through ths array
for(var i = 0, l = ths.length; i <= l; i += 1){
    // select each column of tds
    // set the data-value attribute of each element
    $(".table td:nth-of-type(" + (i + 1) + ")").attr("data-title", ths[i]);
}
```

If you wanted, you could make it even simpler by doing this:

```
// loop through the TH elements
$(".table th").each(function (i) {
    // get and trim HTML of TH
    var thdatatrimmed = trimIt($(this).html());
    // select each column of TDs
    $(".table td:nth-of-type(" + (i + 1) + ")")
        // set the data-value attribute of each element
        .attr("data-title", thdatatrimmed);
});
```

**[JSfiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/zqh2myhk/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
//array to fill with ths
var ths = new Array();

//Clean the text
function trimIt(x) {
    return x.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
}
//Fill ths array with header text
$(".table th").each(function () {
    var thdatatrimmed = trimIt($(this).html());
    ths.push(thdatatrimmed);
});

//total trs
var trlen = $(".table tr").length;
console.log(trlen);
console.log(ths);
//add header to data-title attribute to each TD

$('.table tr').each(function(){
 $(this).find('td').each(function(index,td){
    //console.log(td,index); 
        $(td).attr('data-title',ths[index]);
    });
});
```

```css
 .demo {
     border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
     border-collapse:collapse;
     padding:5px;
 }
 .demo th {
     border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
     padding:5px;
     background:#F0F0F0;
 }
 .demo td {
     border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
     padding:5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table demo">
    <tr>
        <th>Table 1</th>
        <th>Table 2</th>
        <th>Table 3</th>
        <th>Table 4</th>
        <th>Table 5</th>
        <th>Table 6</th>
        <th>Table 7</th>
        <th>Table 8</th>
        <th>Table 9</th>
        <th>Table 10</th>
        <th>Table 11</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```